# How to use Django decorators for Piston handler methods?

Tags: python, django, django-piston

Is it possible to use Django (and self-made) view decorators with Piston handler methods? The problem is that with the methods, the first argument is `self` (the handler) and the second the `request`, while for the methods the first argument is the `request`.

Basically I'd like to do something like this:

```
from piston.handler import BaseHandler
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    @permission_required(lambda u: u.is_staff or u.is_superuser)
    def read(self, request, foo, bar):
        # do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    @method_decorator(permission_required(lambda u: u.is_staff or u.is_superuser))
    def read(self, request, foo, bar):
        # do something
```